# convert date column to another time-zone then group by day of week

Tags: sql, sqlite, date, sql-update, strftime

Part of a database that I have is in this example format:

| Value | Date (UTC format) |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | `Fri Jul 18 02:28:32 +0000 2014` |
| 20 | `Mon Oct 05 10:21:41 +0000 2015` |
| 30 | `Mon Oct 12 09:11:42 +0000 2015` |

I would like to group the values based on the day of the week so the query would return something like this:

| Total Count | Day of Week (UTC format) |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | Fri |
| 50 | Mon |

But before that, I need to convert the date from UTC to PDT which might affect the day of the week. For instance, `Fri Jul 18 02:28:32 +0000 2014` from the first row in UTC would be a Thursday in PDT. As such, I need to convert the timezone first and then query the updated day of the week, which would be something like:

| Total Count | Day of Week (PDT format) |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | Thu |
| 50 | Mon |

I tried starting off my query with `SELECT DATETIME(date, 'PDT')` but it doesn't work.

Comment: SQLite's date functions do not work for the format that you have for your dates. The only valid text format is YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.sss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is the format of the dates that you store in the table does not work with the [datetime functions of SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).
The only acceptable text format for dates is `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.sss`.

I propose that you update the table with this format, so that the dates you have are directly usable by SQLite and are also comparable:

```
UPDATE tablename 
SET Date = SUBSTR(Date, -4) || '-' ||
           CASE SUBSTR(Date, 5, 3)
             WHEN 'Jan' THEN '01'
             WHEN 'Feb' THEN '02'
             WHEN 'Mar' THEN '03'
             WHEN 'Apr' THEN '04'
             WHEN 'May' THEN '05'
             WHEN 'Jun' THEN '06'
             WHEN 'Jul' THEN '07'
             WHEN 'Aug' THEN '08'
             WHEN 'Sep' THEN '09'
             WHEN 'Oct' THEN '10'
             WHEN 'Nov' THEN '11'
             WHEN 'Dec' THEN '12'
           END || '-' ||
           SUBSTR(Date, 9, 11);
```

Then, join a CTE that returns the days of the week to the table and aggregate:

```
WITH cte(nr, day) AS (VALUES ('0', 'Sun'), ('1', 'Mon'), ('2', 'Tue'), ('3', 'Wed'), ('4', 'Thu'), ('5', 'Fri'), ('6', 'Sat'))
SELECT c.day,
       SUM(Value) total_value
FROM tablename t INNER JOIN cte c
ON c.nr = strftime('%w', DATETIME(t.Date, '-7 hour'))
GROUP BY c.day
ORDER BY c.nr;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=7ca63c7a6fbf8ac94b75a61936334824).

If you don't want to change the format of the dates, then you must include in your aggregation query the transformation of the dates to the correct format:

```
WITH cte(nr, day) AS (VALUES ('0', 'Sun'), ('1', 'Mon'), ('2', 'Tue'), ('3', 'Wed'), ('4', 'Thu'), ('5', 'Fri'), ('6', 'Sat'))
SELECT c.day,
       SUM(Value) total_value
FROM tablename t INNER JOIN cte c
ON c.nr = strftime(
            '%w', 
            DATETIME(
              SUBSTR(t.Date, -4) || '-' ||
              CASE SUBSTR(t.Date, 5, 3)
                WHEN 'Jan' THEN '01'
                WHEN 'Feb' THEN '02'
                WHEN 'Mar' THEN '03'
                WHEN 'Apr' THEN '04'
                WHEN 'May' THEN '05'
                WHEN 'Jun' THEN '06'
                WHEN 'Jul' THEN '07'
                WHEN 'Aug' THEN '08'
                WHEN 'Sep' THEN '09'
                WHEN 'Oct' THEN '10'
                WHEN 'Nov' THEN '11'
                WHEN 'Dec' THEN '12'
              END || '-' ||
              SUBSTR(t.Date, 9, 11), 
              '-7 hour'
            )
          )
GROUP BY c.day
ORDER BY c.nr;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=3fe5cc3564c7bbda0a59c6e2c3fee541).